# How to report a column header based on the maximum value, but only when that value exceeds a specific value?

Tags: excel, match

I am trying to create a formula that reports the column label based on the highest value in a rown, but I am having problems stopping it doing it when the value is not equal to or greater than 13.

Here I have the formula I am using in cell K2 to generate the heading/category of the highest value

[image]

As You can see row 2 is fine, because the value is above 13, so it has done exactly what I want, however row 3 has reported "control" as it is the highest value, but is not meeting the criteria of being equal or greater than 13.

How do I include a criteria for the match function please? everything I have tried results in an error (mostly saying that I cant use >= in the function). I have tried several individual If statements for each column, but it stated too many arguments. I have also tried Maxif, but cant seem to get it to work either. Equally, I have tried specifying a Max value of 13 and using the match type , -1, but again it doesn't notice it.

At present I am working with:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$I$1,0,MATCH(MAX($E2:$I2),$E2:$I2,0 ))
```

Please help me learn how to include a criteria

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following setup:

[image]

The Formula I used in K2 was the following:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$I$1,MATCH(MAX(E2:I2)&TRUE,E2:I2&(E2:I2>=13),0)),"Did not meet criteria")}
```

The brackets `{}` aren't part of the formula, they just indicate, that this is an so called array formula. This needs to be entered with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Explanation:
The `IFERROR`-Part is used to catch the case, that the criteria is not fulfilled, since the Index-Match combination will return an `#NA`-Error.
The first part `INDEX($E$1:$I$1` specifies the range of the headings we want to draw from. 
Now the fun part. The Match-Function takes three arguments. The first specifies the Value which will be looked up. The second specifies the range in which the value is looked for and the third what kind of match is required.
`MAX(E2:I2)` returns the maximal value in `E2:I2`. In this case this would be 16. The `&` operator concatenates two values. If you have two strings it would simply put them together. For example "Hello " & "World" would return "Hello World". In our case we abuse this. `MAX(E2:I2)&TRUE` returns `16TRUE`. So our `MATCH` function will search for this. In the second argument of the `MATCH`-function we abuse the concatenating-operator again. If you have two ranges of the same length the `&` operator simply merges the two corresponding values of the ranges. In our case it would look like `{1FALSE,0FALSE,16TRUE,4FALSE,4FALSE}`.
So the `MATCH`-function (which is looking for `16TRUE`) will return 3.

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked a treat! On top of that I have finally learned what array formulas are and how to use them on a basic level. I really appreciate it

Comment: @StevenHaworth No Problem, if you want me to elaborate how the formula works, just say so and I will try to explain.

Comment: Yes please, for sheer educational purposes some elaboration would be wonderul. My understanding of it is as follows: The iferror function is used to enable us to check for errors in the formula, (INDEX($E$1:$I$1 specifies the range of the headings I want to draw from for my true statements. and MATCH(MAX(E2:I2)&TRUE,E2:I2&(E2:I2>=13),0)) refers to the calculations that decide if its a true or false response, however I am very confused by the use of the &'s. In particular, why "&TRUE,E2:I2&(E2:I2>=13)"? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @ Marco Getrost, thank you so very much. It clarifies everything for me. You are a star!